# Como substituir um espaço por ponto e vírgula entre duas palavras com o gsub()

Tags: r, regex

Tenho um problema para resolver e não consigo escrever a regex correta. Quero acrescentar o ponto e vírgula entre dois emails:

```
ex <- "jose@gmail.com joao@gmail.com.br"

#resultado esperado:
[1] "jose@gmail.com;joao@gmail.com.br"
```

Agradeço pela ajuda!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aqui vai:

```
ex <- "jose@gmail.com joao@gmail.com.br"

# Com o gsub()
gsub(pattern = "[[:blank:]]",
     replacement = ";",
     x =  ex)

# Com str_replace_all(), que eu prefiro
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(string = ex,
                pattern = "[[:blank:]]",
                replacement = ";")
```

Você também poderia fazer isso:

```
str_replace_all(string = ex,
                pattern = "[ ]",
                replacement = ";")
```

Ou então isso:

```
str_replace_all(string = ex,
                pattern = "[[:space:] ]",
                replacement = ";")
```

`[[:blank:]]` funciona para eliminar todo tipo de espaço em branco, inclusive tabs, etc. Com `[ ]` (um espaço entre colchetes) você só remove o espaço comum mesmo. E com `[[:space:]]` é possível eliminar espaços, tabs e também quebras de linha.

Comment: eu estava escrevendo o [[:blank:]] errado e não estava dando certo. Obrigada!